# Python DateParseError with dtype: datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I get this error 'DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: Datetime' with the following numpy.where statement:

```
dfall['dBV']=numpy.where(dfall.loc['Datetime'].hour==0,dfall.onBV,dfall.BV)
```

This function is used before I try to use the numpy.where statement:

```
dfall['Datetime']=pandas.to_datetime(dfall['Datetime'],format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

When I call dfall.Datetime I get the following:   Name: Datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

The data frame is in the following format:

```
Date        Time       Datetime
2016-02-01  00:00:00   2016-02-01 00:00:00
            08:30:00   2016-02-01 08:30:00
            08:31:00   2016-02-01 08:31:00
            08:32:00   2016-02-01 08:32:00
            08:33:00   2016-02-01 08:33:00
```

I have a feeling this may be related to the hierarchical index, but since I am new to using this type of index I am struggling for a solution. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.loc` selects rows, not columns: use `dfall['Datetime']` instead of  `dfall.loc['Datetime']`.

Comment: I have tried that as well and receive:
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'hour'`

Comment: You are missing the datetime accessor: `dfall['Datetime'].dt.hour`

Comment: That does it.  Stupid mistake.  Thank you for the catch.